# Term for spelling out letters with your body

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a term for people spelling out a name or some other word with their bodies (e.g. [YMCA](http://pigroll.com/img/ymca.jpg)), usually for the purposes of a fun photo? This is similar to sign language but uses the whole body with arms and legs.

Comment: I thought [_semaphore_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore), but discovered I was wrong. It involves flags.

Comment: @sarah - Actually, semaphore uses the position of the arms, the flags are just to make it more visible from a distance. A fine example is in Authur Ransome's "Missee Lee".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I remember, it's called ***Acrobatic Alphabet***.

[image]

N.B.: After some googling, I've found the term ***Human Alphabet***. You can check out the results from [this link](http://www.google.com/search?q=human%20alphabet).

Comment: *Acrobatic Alphabet* seems more appropriate, though it has a limited scope. Probably it is what the OP asked, in fact.  Thanks, I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: @Kris Why would you edit your answer to include someone else's answer?

Comment: @onomatomaniak Certainly, to indicate the correction and to point to the source.

Comment: thanks .. i just wanted the right search terms for some ideas for 'H' shapes, but had no idea what to google!

Comment: @wim Looks like you need a partner for the "H" though :)

Comment: @Matt and also for D.  And while not shown in Mehper's graphic the more legible variant of W returned by Google is also a two person character.

Answer (score 1):

***formation***

Santas in **[Star Formation](http://uk.ibtimes.com/articles/273425/20111228/unique-santas-spotted-around-world-2011-photos.htm)**: Schoolchildren dressed as Santa Claus form the shape of a star ahead of Christmas celebrations ... [Source: Reuters Date:12/28/2011]
[image]

In various contexts not limited to using the human body alone, this pattern is commonly known as a *formation*. We usually see aircraft flying in formation.

[Formation flying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_flying) is the disciplined flight of two or more aircraft ...
In civil aviation, formation flying is performed at air shows and is also flown for recreation.

[Formation skydiving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_skydiving) is the art of building formations in free-fall with multiple people gripping each others' limbs or specially built "grippers" on their jumpsuits.

A **[V formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_formation)** (sometimes called a skein) is the symmetric V-shaped flight formation of flights of geese, ducks, and other migratory birds. V formations are also used on military flight missions.

Crop circles are also referred to as [crop formations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_circle), because they are not always circular in shape.

In association football, the [formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_%28association_football%29) describes how the players in a team are positioned on the pitch.

[Formation dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_dance) is a style of ballroom dancing. It is pattern or shadow team dancing by couples in a formation team.

---

[EDIT-1: As suggested by @Mehper C. Palavuzlar]
***Acrobatic Alphabet*** / ***Human Alphabet*** may be more appropriate depending on the OP's question.

[Alphabet Recreation](http://www.designswan.com/archives/amazing-recreation-of-alphabet-by-human-body.html) has all the alphabet formations in photographs.